# rows to columns for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  category value 
0        A    12
1        B     6
2        C     5
3        D     9
4        A     2
5        B     7
6        C     3
7        D    11
```

And I'm trying to get to look like this:

```
 A   B   C   D
12   6   5   9
 2   7   3  11
```

I've tried using **unstack** and **pivot**, but I haven't able to get either to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question 10 *How to pivot with two columns* on the dup link.

Comment: Thanks, the answer to Question 10 is exactly what I needed.